# Show only part of the line found by grep (but not the part that matches the pattern)

Tags: text-processing, grep

In `ifcfg-eth0`, I managed to grep "DEVICE=eth0" by using

```
grep "DEVICE=" ifcfg-eth0
```

But how can I grep pattern to show only "eth0"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`grep` is not really the tool for this (although versions of GNU grep offer various options that do similar things). `sed` or `awk` are far better suited for this task.

```
awk -F= '$1 == "DEVICE" { print $2 }'
```

```
sed -n 's/^DEVICE=//p'
```

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to do this using GNU `grep` with the `-P` option (PCRE). It is important note that not all versions of GNU `grep` are compiled with support for the `-P` option.

I would personally use `awk` as recommended by Chris Down, but I wanted to provide the `grep` answer requested for completeness.

```
grep -Po '(?<=DEVICE=).+' ifcfg-eth0
```

The `(?<=)` construct is known as a `look-behind`. It is used to find the match, but not included in the actual match.